# Re-Enable Shutdown Messages Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, shutdown

I have a machine running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS server.

At some point it stopped the verbose onscreen kernel messages during a shutdown or reboot, including the status of the stopping of services.

For the most part the screen is just empty now, without any messages showing the status of shutdown.

The messages I am thinking of are the same you'd see by default in Debian and if you tapped <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the splash screen for a standard Ubuntu install.

The startup messages still show, it's only the shutdown messages.

A setting may have been changed at some point to change this behavior, but if so, I can't remember what.

The value of **`kernel.printk`** in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf` is `4 4 1 7`

The value for **`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`** is `maybe-ubiquity`. There are no `quiet` or `splash` values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try commenting out `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` in `/etc/default/grub`, then `$ sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Hi. As I mentioned in my post "quiet" and "splash" are not present.

Comment: The line is currently: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"`

Comment: Have a look in `/etc/default/grub.d/50-curtin.cfg` and `/etc/default/grub.d/50-curtin-settings.cfg` files, it seems to be a bug of Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS installation.

What is the output of `$ uname -r` and `$ lsb_release -a`?

Maybe its a incompleted installation.